# WPF ItemsControl horizontal orientation and fill parent?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to horizontally place the items in an ItemControl whilst making them fill the parent control.

Here is my XAMl:

```
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnnualWeatherViewModels}" Visibility="{Binding IsAnnualWeatherViewModels, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <V:AerosolSimpleWeatherCharacteristicsView DataContext="{Binding}"></V:AerosolSimpleWeatherCharacteristicsView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

The two variations I have tried for `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` are:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
```

and:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False"></DockPanel>
```

However neither achieve the desired result, the `StackPanel` compresses all the items and the `DockPanel` will either fill the space of the parent control with a large portion of space dedicated to the last item or not fill the parent space depending on the value of `LastChildFill`.

So how can I layout the items of my `ItemsControl` horizontally and have them fill the space of the parent control?

I ended up creating this custom control as sugested in the answer:

```
public partial class StretchingPanel : Grid
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(StretchingPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FillFirstItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FillFirstItem", typeof(bool), typeof(StretchingPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FillFirstItemFactorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FillFirstItemFactor", typeof(double), typeof(StretchingPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.8));

        public Orientation Orientation
        {
            get
            {
                return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(OrientationProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool FillFirstItem
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(FillFirstItemProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(FillFirstItemProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public double FillFirstItemFactor
        {
            get
            {
                return (double)GetValue(FillFirstItemFactorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(FillFirstItemFactorProperty, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
        {
            if (Orientation == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; ++i)
                {
                    var column = new ColumnDefinition();
                    if (i == 0 && FillFirstItem)
                        column.Width = new GridLength(FillFirstItemFactor, GridUnitType.Star);
                    ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
                    Grid.SetColumn(Children[i], i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RowDefinitions.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; ++i)
                {
                    var row = new RowDefinition();
                    if (i == 0 && FillFirstItem)
                        row.Height = new GridLength(FillFirstItemFactor, GridUnitType.Star);
                    RowDefinitions.Add(row);
                    Grid.SetRow(Children[i], i);
                }
            }
            base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
        }

        public StretchingPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the property `DataContext="{Binding}"` is redundant. remove it. That would be somewhat equivalent to the following C# code: `this.DataContext = this.DataContext;`

Comment: It is also very convenient to end XAML elements with `/>` instead. For Instance: `<V:AerosolSimpleWeatherCharacteristicsView DataContext="{Binding}"></V:AerosolSimpleWeatherCharacteristicsView>` can be reduced to `<V:AerosolSimpleWeatherCharacteristicsView/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to proportionally stretch the items. If it is achievable at all with standard Panels, it's with Grid (which can have proportional columns), this would require setting ColumnDefinitions after the ItemSource changes.

It's simple with a custom Panel:

```
class ProportionallyStretchingPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            child.Measure(availableSize);
        return availableSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double widthSum = 0.0;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            widthSum += child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }
        double x = 0.0;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            double proportionalWidth = child.DesiredSize.Width / widthSum * availableSize.Width;
            child.Arrange(
                new Rect(
                    new Point(x, 0.0),
                    new Point(x + proportionalWidth, availableSize.Height)));
            x += proportionalWidth;
        }
        return availableSize;
    }
}

<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <local:ProportionallyStretchingPanel"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: Your right the only way to do it was by creating a custom panel, so I created one of grid, see my updated question.

Answer (score 13):

`UniformGrid` does the job.

```
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: The controls being added to the ItemsControl are not all the same size, it needs to do it on a per-control basis or something. UniformGrid ends up warping everything by trying to make them all the same size.

Comment: Just wanted to say this was EXACTLY what I needed. I had never heard of UniformGrid before and I feel like I've cheated myself out of so many possibilities for a simple solution. Thank you!